# Derivative, Calculus

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Under what conditions we can write:
$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = g(f)$

where $f$ is assumed to be function of $x$ and $t$, for example.

Comment: Is there any condition need to write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = g(f)$?

Comment: @HoseynHeydari For example $f=x^2e^t$, $g$ cannot be written in terms of $f$, indeed $g=g(f,x)$.